# How to generate productFlavors in parallel in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have created different productFlavors of android app so build them in parallel,
is there any way to build productFlavors in parallel using gradle.

I want to generate multiple apk's

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear enough, are you trying to build apk files for all the flavors? If that's the case then you can enter this command while you are in the directory where gradle is installed

```
gradlew clean assembleFlavoreOne assembleFlavorTwo assembleFlavorThree
```